# Hello, I try to run my c code in dev-c++ and get this : [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode

Tags: windows, dev-c++

#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
printf("Hello \n");

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<30; j++)
    printf("%c", (char)179);

printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

printf("what\ up \n ");

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<30; j++)
    printf("%c", (char)179); 

printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

printf("Are you enjoying programming \n");

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<30; j++)
    printf("%c", (char)179); 

printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, initial declaration of the loop counter needs to be outside the loop, ie:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
//do stuff here
}
```

In-loop initial declaration, as your error message suggests, can be used only in C99 or C11 standard (which is C standard published in 1999 and 2011).